# Object List from Selection

Tags: animation-nodes

I would like to create an object list from my selected objects but I can't find a way of doing this on 2.80 and AN 2.1.

If this isn't possible, what are the alternatives for animating multiple different objects?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Create a collection and set the wanted objects in it (upper right part of the image above).

Then use a "Collection Info" node in the node setting and use the collection as input.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @lemon. 

But what about using Matrices instead? Becase ID Key doesn't seems to work. 

[link]https://i.gyazo.com/d14fa7c0379d92c549a4772e6e126a59.png[/link]

Comment: @DimitriPaiva, this is not related to collections

Comment: I don't understood your answer. Should I create another topic instead?

Comment: @DimitriPaiva, I don't know because I don't understand what you mean with id keys and matrices as this is not related to the fact you can get several objects with a collection. What do you want to do with these objects?

Comment: I would like to animate these objects under a collection considering their position on the viewport. When I connect the Collection info on any node with transforms output, like Object Transforms Output ou Matrix Object Output, all the objects suddenly goes to 0,0,0 XYZ on the viewport, ignoring their initial position. 
That's why I asked about ID Keys, which is a way to "define" the initial transforms of the objects, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It seems matrix does not support list transforms (list of matrices combined with another one). But that said, for ID keys, this is a way to get some initial value (stored by animation nodes) that you can reuse in your calculation. But if you just reinput the ID keys as they are, objects will stay as they are (also consider using "from current transform" in the AN tool in the 3D view in order to catch the initial ID keys you want).

Comment: But yes, globally, if comments are not easy enough to solve it, this should be another question, I think.